# Limit a range of ip addresses to specific ports using iptables

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I am using iptables v1.4.21 on linux. I am trying to limit traffic for DHCP clients `10.0.0.50-10.0.0.100`. I would like them to only have access to ports `53,67,80,443,9091,32400` using `TCP` and `UDP`. But I can't seem to find something that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combination of these  rules will do it:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m iprange --src-range 10.0.0.50-10.0.0.100  -p tcp --match multiport --dports 53,67,80,443,9091,32400 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m iprange --src-range 10.0.0.50-10.0.0.100  -p udp --match multiport --dports 53,67,80,443,9091,32400 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m iprange --src-range 10.0.0.50-10.0.0.100   -j DROP
```

Nothing smart in this: two rules for `UDP` and `TCP`, respectively, allowing traffic. The module `iprange` allows specification of a range of IP addresses to which the rule applies, the `--match multiports` allows to match `any` of a list of ports. The last rule examines packets which **do not** satisfy either of the previous two criteria, dropping them, as per your request.

Comment: Does it matter if the third line isn't above the two others?

Comment: @Tloz Yes it does. It is important that the last line comes after the previous two. In iptables, rules are examined *sequentially*: when a match is found, no more rules are tested. In the order above, if either of the first two rules applies, the packet is accepted, and the third rule is **not** tested. But if the first two rules do not apply, the third rule is tested and, if it pplies, it causes the packet to be rejected.

Comment: Oh, this explain why my rules never work! I thought that you had to put the less specific first

Comment: @Tloz Nope, that is the correct rule for routing tables, not for iptables.